# Как, после нажатия одной из кнопок, заблокировать другие?

Tags: javascript

Есть 10 кнопок. Нужно, чтобы после нажатия одной из них, другие кнопки становились неактивными.
Вот код кнопки:

```
document.getElementById('addButton0').onclick = function(){

   if (this.className == 'button') {

     this.className = 'blueColor';

     let num = 1;

   }

  else {

     this.className = 'button';

     let num = 0;

   }

   document.body.onclick = function() {

       num = +!num;

   }

}
```

Comment: А для чего здесь `num` ? let объявляет переменную после каждого клика, которая нигде не используется и благополучно забывается.

Comment: Мне это нужно для теста: пользователь отвечает на два вопроса, а потом система находит кнопки, которые имеют переменную, равную 1, и на основе этого выдаётся результат.

Answer (score 2):

#### Первое

Вы сами понимаете код который вы написали? На самом деле тут полная бессмыслица, достаточно того что вы **при каждом клике на кнопку вешаете событие клик на body**, зачем?

Как вы собираетесь получить num? У него **блочная область видимости**, и каждый раз при клике на элемент addButton0 создаётся новая переменная **num** которая **не видна в других блоках**.

```
   document.body.onclick = function() {

      num = +!num; // Тут вы не сможете получить num который объявили в if/else

   }
```

#### Второе

Простительно, что люди задают вопросы на которые не знают ответа, ведь для этого и нужна Stack Overflow.

Но не простительно, что вы просите помощи при этом сами не хотите помочь. Вы просто скинули кусок кода который у вас был, что-то написали и ждёте решения, не отформатировали вопрос, не подумали и почитали сами.

Помощь людей заключается не в написании решения, они могут подсказать где что почитать и узнать, чтобы вы поняли в чем ошибка.

Я советую вам [Современный учебник JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/) Начинайте с самого начала